# Django admin template customization

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a django admin site with multiple apps and also multiple admin sites inside and I need to add a logo for all pages.

I've made it work by adding a index_template a and extending the base_site.html with my logo.

**Admin Site**

```
class xxxxAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    site_header = "xxx"
    site_title = "xxx"
    index_title = "xxx"
    index_template = "index.html"
```

**Base Site.html**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">
    <img src="{% static 'xxx.png' %}" height="40px" />
</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

The problem is I'm currently changing the pages for all scenario's of the admin site eg. change_form_template, change_list_template, etc. But I need to add change_form_template and change_list template for all my admin.ModelAdmin's

**ModelAdmin**

```
class xxxxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'
    change_list_template = 'change_list.html'
    delete_confirmation_template = 'delete_confirmation.html'
    object_history_template = 'object_history.html'
```

Any cleaner way to do it? Something like all model admins to point to a single eg. change_form?.

Comment: You can just change the template and store it in the relevant `templates/admin` directory or your main app.  As long as the app it is declared before `django` in `INSTALLED_APPS` it will be used. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories)

Comment: Got it working thanks just moving the app above the django.contrib.admin worked!!